# Should we use Java Component in Mule, if component is already available? Mule Performance and Optimization

Tags: java, mule, transformer-model

It is accepted that we should use available Mule Components to achieve particular functionality rather then, using Custom Java Transformers.

The case is that i already have Mule component to perform particular functionality, 
But instead of using that, i introduced Java Transformer to achieve the same functionality.

I need a comparison between performance of two, as i am unable to find some speed issue.

but still i want to know:

Will it deteriorates performance? Will it make application slow in future?

I am unable to get answer for the same in forums. 
If anyone could comment on same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using your own implementations won't slow things down (unless you implement them badly) but why would you do that if Mule provides what you need out-of-the-box? Better use a transformer that is widely used and thus has been tested and debugged for you already.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Nice reason for using inbuilt and 
I was just making it confirm, whether out the box components deteriorates performance in any way. As when i was damn new to Mule (with Java Background), i was unable to get usage of few transformers and i just put Java transformer and wrote code in it. 

Now i am getting familiar with components day by day and i feel like refactoring previous work which i did in to mule components itself. There is no speed issue as such, but was concern about underlying performance issues in long run, but if no issue, i can concentrate on future work.